# How to index and search SFTP/SSH files in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, search, sftp

I use [Index Your Files](http://www.indexyourfiles.com/) to index and search shared network locations quickly in Windows. I found some files on a shared network location. When I opened this network location in WinSCP I found that it is actually /home/sharedfolder.

Searching these locations using WinSCP takes a lot of time therefore I want to index / and /home as well. Is there any software for that?

Below is the server information (using WinSCP) where the shared folder is located:

- Session protocol: SSH-2
- SSH implementation: OpenSSH_4.3
- File transfer protocol: SFTP-3

Comment: What is "Index Your Files? Is it indexyourfiles.com? "I opened it in WinSCP": What did you open?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes it is (edited in question). I opened this network location in WinSCP

Comment: So you run "Index your Files" on Windows and use it to search some server? Does "Index your Files" support SFTP? I do not see anything like that on their website.

Comment: No it does not support SFTP that is why I am asking to index that server.

Comment: So how do you use Index Your Files with that server? (Sorry, but I really do not understand the point. And it seems that's am not the only one, providing lack of any answers.)

Comment: I might be wrong about SFTP. All I did was Open IYF, indexed shared network location (\\10.3.20.65\ssc), opened this location in WinSCP (connected as SFTP), found that full path is \home\something\ssc, got some read access to \home and other folders and want to index all those with data. I think it is SAMBA server (don't know how it works)

Comment: Ok, now it makes much more sense. So you need to configure SAMBA to share whole `/home` folder, not just `/home/something/ssc`. If you update your question with this information and mainly update the tags (remove sftp+ssh, add samba), I'm sure you get some good answers. I do not know SAMBA myself.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I don't have admin access to the server. So there is no way I can configure it.

Comment: You are out of luck then, I'm afraid.

Comment: Np. I have posted a summary answer to close this question off. Please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted in comments, the server is using SAMBA to share folders.

So you need to configure SAMBA to share whole `/home` folder, not just `/home/something/ssc` to make it available for "Index Your Files".

Knowing that you do not have rights to modify SAMBA configuration, I'm afraid there's no solution for you, unless you find other software that can use SFTP for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually there is a solution (even though I have my reservations on it).

Seems like Index Your Files works on local drives, and does not support SFTP. But you can always mount the remote SFTP server as a local drive using software specifically designed for that purpose, like [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/), or [WebDrive](http://southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/).

Once your SFTP server is seen by the operating system as a local drive, then you can use Index Your Files to index the contents of that pseudo-local drive. The caveat is that when you go FIND stuff, the location you'll get is the file location relative to the virtual drive, and not the real SFTP URL to the file on the server, therefore the virtual drive client will need to become a constant piece of software in your setup.